# is there a word for half sibling's half sibling?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a half brother on my mom's side. He has a half sister on his dad's side. Is there a single word/term for describing that sister's relation to me? Currently I just say "my half brother's half sister".

Comment: @sumelic cross sibling works! hopefully peeople know what I mean when I say it... Ill close the question, just wish there was a more mainstream word as this is a pretty typical situation

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that none of the existing terms are fully satisfying.

Comment: "Quarter sibling" could be used colloquially, but it does not relate to the correct but inoften-used "three-quarter sibling".